# What's causing my images to disappear in Chrome, but show correct in IE?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, modernizr

I'm starting to transition into a role of Webmaster for a university club website. They just rolled out a new boilerplate site that uses **jquery-1.10.1.min** and **modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min**.

In IE, everything looks how it's supposed to. All of the images/icons appear where they're supposed to.

In Chrome, two icons in one section of the footer disappear, and another image in the index disappears.

Chrome developer tools shows me that this elements are having these styles applied:

```
element.style {
 display: none !important;
 visibility: hidden !important;
 opacity: 0 !important;
 background-position: 1px 1px;
}
```

`element.style` meaning that the style is being applied by JS.

There are no PHP scripts being used to generate these images.
There are no JS scripts being used except jquery and modernizr.

They're just plain `<img src="img/facebook.png" class="class">` tags. Changing the class doesn't help.

If I change a working `<img>` to have a src of `img/facebook.png`, then the working image stops working.

If I change `img/facebook.png` to `img/email.png`, which is a working icon, then the image appears.

If I copy `facebook.png` and rename it to `fbicon.png` it still doesn't work.
If I copy `facebook.png` and rename it to `email2.png` it *does* work. (WTF?)

For reference, the complete list of image *names* that don't work is:

- facebook.png
- twitter.png
- fbicon.png
- social.png

I'm not familiar with modernizr at all, which seems more likely to be the culprit than jQuery.

<strike>What would cause the disabling of images with social media-based names in Chrome (Version 40)?</strike>

**Update:** Does Chrome or modernizr programmatically hide images that fail to load, to prevent showing red X blocks that may effect layouts?

The issue is with Chrome 40 on a Win 8.1 Update 1 desktop (although my laptop has the same OS/Browsers as my desktop.)

I'm having the issue on my *desktop* with **both** the live server and the test server which runs completely off my desktop. My test server is using XAMPP for Apache (don't know the version # offhand, I can get that when I'm home). I don't have access to the production PHP server, but I assume it's also a similar version of Apache.

The issue appears both in Chrome and in DreamWeaver's Design/Live modes.

My desktop accesses the website using my own Internet connection, but I also VPN in to the University network. My laptop, which is currently working fine, is using one of the University's WiFi networks.

Comment: Are you able to disable modernizr? If so, try it so you can rule it out as a suspect. My site uses modernizr and a facebook.png file with no problems. Also, does your HTML file have an inline style affecting those images? Suppose there's a tag like `<img style="display: none;" src="..."/>` then your CSS can't help you I don't think. You need to fix it inline first.

Comment: There are no inline styles on *anything* in the site, classes, IDs only. I've combed all the css files to see if some errant child selector is at work, to no avail. I'll try disabling modernizr for the test server later, but I don't know how much of the site utilizes it. It was a nightmare just to figure out the filenames were the issue. I tried placing the exact images all over the site, and they never work in Chrome, regardless of the parent tag. I'm probably going to use generic names and call it good.

Comment: Can you share the site? The community could help more with access to the problem as you see it.

Comment: I can't share the code tonight, and I won't have time to access it again for about 18 hours. The public facing version is [here](http://www.isumisclub.com/). The images in the footer are the problem. The email icons work, social media don't. However, Chrome on my *tablet* displays them fine.

Comment: I'm looking at the live version in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11 in Windows 7. They all show the same content. Moreover, the Facebook and Twitter icons definitely show in Chrome. The `element.styles` is empty on my end, however.

Comment: I can't see any images using chrome - I'm getting ´ERR_CONNECTION_RESET´ - can there be some permissions on the server side that is blocking content?

Comment: @Tapirboy Not sure. The server is actually managed by the University. But, for our allocated space we have no .htaccess or anything blocking permissions. All the images are in the same directory, too. I should note now that it's working on my laptop right now, no problems. So it's probably a server error.

Comment: As @ThisClark says - all is good on Win7. I'm using Chrome 40. You should definitely specify the Chrome and OS versions. Also, are you able to access the images directly? For instance: http://www.mis.stuorg.iastate.edu/img/facebook.png

Comment: @Boaz I updated with my OS and Browser info. But, they're the exact same as my laptop which has *no* problems with this. I can access the image directly on my laptop. I'll try the desktop when I get home.

Comment: The VPN might be the key here. It might be that the university's VPN is trying to block anything related to social networking, including resources with keywords such as `facebook` or `twitter` in their path.

Comment: @Boaz AFAIK, the VPN is only necessary to establish the SFTP connection. Regardless, it should have no effect on the local copy of the site running completely on my machine. But, that local copy has the same problem. It's actually how I noticed the problem to begin with, because I saw the `<img>` tags in the HTML but noticed they weren't displaying. *Then* I checked the live website to see if it were just my copy acting up, but found I had the same issue.

Comment: It makes sense The VPN is probably only needed for uploading the local version to the remote server. But while connected to it other kinds of traffic are routed through it as well. Are you connected to the VPN while trying to access the local version? If so, it might be causing a similar issue there somehow. Try accessing the local version without connecting to the VPN first.

Comment: Following @Boaz line of thought, it's possible your university has some problem in their DNS records that messes with your images loading properly. If you've only tested the site while on their WiFi and while connected to their VPN then maybe it interferes. Test locally while not connected to their network and see if the problem goes away. It may not be necessary but while testing offline also flush your dns registration in command line as administrator: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: I'm skeptical a VPN would affect my localhost without some really odd configurations. Nevertheless, I just tested it. I have nothing running but Apache on XAMPP, and the problem persists for both the live version and my local version. I ran `/flush dns` and cleared the cache. However, this line of thought led me to something else. I figured out the answer, and now feel like a total idjit.

Comment: Indulge us - answer your own question and mark it closed :) I'm curious after this long discussion what the source was.

Comment: @ThisClark I was just doing that! I only figured out the culprit *as* I was typing the comment above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The issue was Chrome, specifically a Chrome Extension: *AdBlock* was responsible for blocking the images.**

I have AdBlock installed on both of my machines (my extensions are all synced with my Google account), so I didn't expect an extension to be the problem. My laptop subscribes to the same block lists, but doesn't have this issue.

However, hindsight is 20/20. The fact that it was social media related icons that were being blocked should have been a key.

Comment: Hilarious - glad you figured it out. It's still very strange though. I've got AdBlock installed and I saw the images just fine - maybe you have some additional block rules you previously setup. Regardless - case closed!

Comment: I subscribe to: AdBlock custom filters, EasyList, and Fanboy's Annoyances, otherwise I have no filters except domain exceptions. It's probably Fanboy's that's the problem: It's not a default option, and I may not have checked it on my laptop when AB auto-installed.